# Delete AWS CloudFormation stack but preserve Route53 record set

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

*Context:* I have been using CloudFormation for provisioning application resources for a while, and that has worked out just fine. However, I recently moved my application over to different infrastructure (Kubernetes), and to go live with that change, I modified the Route53 DNS record to point to the new resources, and left up all the AWS resources created by CloudFormation. For clarity, the DNS record which I modified was created as part of the CloudFormation stack.

*Problem:* I want to delete the now unused resources, including the CloudFormation stack itself. However, doing so would either delete a DNS record that I very much care about, or fail to delete the DNS record because it has been modified, rolling back the entire operation.

*Question*: **Does anybody know a clever way I can remove a CloudFormation stack while still preserving the Route53 entries created by it with zero downtime?**

*Note:* I do not want to manually delete the resources created by CloudFormation, except for the DNS records, and leave the stack hanging around.

Comment: Read about deletion policy, and retain. You may be able to modify your template to indicate "DeletionPolicy" : "Retain" for the relevant DNS resources, then run a CF update stack, then later run a CF delete stack. Probably worth testing on a throwaway stack before you commit to this route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deny delete privileges for Route53 and delete the stack in 2 phases.

[Delete Stack Fails](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-errors-delete-stack-fails)

> When stacks are in the DELETE_FAILED state because AWS CloudFormation
>   couldn't delete a resource, rerun the deletion with the
>   RetainResources parameter and specify the resource that AWS
>   CloudFormation can't delete. **AWS CloudFormation deletes the stack
>   without deleting the retained resource.** Retaining resources is
>   useful when you can't delete a resource, such as an S3 bucket that
>   contains objects that you want to keep, but you still want to delete
>   the stack. After you delete the stack, you can manually delete
>   retained resources by using their associated AWS service.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a need to preserve my Route53 records that were created with CloudFormation. I performed the following exercise based on @jarmod response and it worked perfectly. The key here is the: `"DeletionPolicy" : "Retain"` More information on the [DeletionPolicy attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html). I'll also note that when I applied the change set to change my deletion policy, CloudFormation DID NOT detect any drift in the Route53 entry. Success!

1. Create a basic CloudFormation stack; Load Balancer, ASG and a Route53 record pointing to the Load Balancer
2. Change the Route53 entry to point to another location using the Route53 console
3. Apply the `"DeletionPolicy" : "Retain"` to my Route53 resource block via a change set
4. Delete the CloudFormation stack from the AWS console
5. Confirm Route53 still has your entries after the stack has been deleted

[Image of CloudFormation Skipping Delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76XBe.png)